# How to show the google map based on lat & lang

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i will give the static latitude and longitude value but google map not showing i refer this link [click here][1].i spent more time in this i can not get solution for this i f any one know means please tell me, my requirement is give the lat & langitude value means i want to show the location

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDKQNg_NX3PCpT5vNMHArnAEAQY9W2hA8M&callback=initMap"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map").get(0), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Are You getting any errors? And what is actually not working? Map is displayed but the center is invalid?

Comment: In my page nothing display,my console page i am getting like this Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

Comment: Well? Did you supply an API key?

Comment: No i did not give any api key, how to get api key and where will give this api key

Comment: Read the documentation you linked to...

Comment: i got api key and i put in my page but still i am geting same error

Comment: Your `loadScript` isn't the same as that in the accepted answer to the question you link to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get API key follow the instructions on this google maps page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key

In the end, your url referencing the google maps api should look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
```

Comment: i got api key and i put in my page but still i am geting same error

Comment: The API key must by part of the url, did you put in your URL when you are saying "I put in my page"?

Comment: Check my updated code i put like this still i am geting error

Comment: You are including the google maps api twice, see the error **You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page**. So remove the second include.

Comment: Check my updated code,now i did not getting any error but nap also not showing what can i do?

Comment: Mr xxxmatko, you also didn't give any api key but working in js fiddle and i copied your code and past in my page  ,and include jquery.min.js file but for me not working , i am getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined(…)

Comment: I wanted to give you the fiddle without API key, so you can see that it is working. And as you said, after pasting the working code into your page, and it is not working, than there must problem elsewhere. Do you have any other scripts on your page?

Comment: I am working on localhost,google map working on localhost or not

Comment: Do you see any other logs in browser console when you run your application? Did rebuild your project? Maybe you are still using cached output from previous requests, hard to say.

Comment: Eb {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Eb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…3PCpT5vNMHArnAEAQY9W2hA8M&callback=initMap:130:73"}

Comment: What is this i can't understand

Comment: It means that you do not have specified function ``initMap`` or that function is defined after referencing the google maps api, which too late

Comment: Now what is the solution Mr xxx

Comment: As I said, the solution is in my answer, you also said that the supplied fiddle is working but in your page, so there is another problem, and without seeing your whole code is hard to say what should you correct.

Comment: K thanks, Mr xxx, now https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation and copy the code put in my api key now working